# How to register click using class and get the id of the clicked item in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im developing a webpage there i need to register a click in jquery using the items class and then get the id of that object.

Example:

html:

```
<div class="exampleclass" id="exampleid1"></div>
<div class="exampleclass" id="exampleid2"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(".exampleclass").click(function(){
Function to get the id
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for get attribute id from NodeElement. In your callback function context `this` is current element where click was maded.

```
$('.exampleclass').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".exampleclass").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`$(this).attr("id")`, or `this.id`

JS

```
$(".exampleclass").click(function(){
   var theID = this.id;
});
```

The callback function gets the execution context set to the element that triggers the event so `this` will refer to the element. As such you can access the different dom properties through it.